# Does S3WritePolicy allow multiple buckets in AWS SAM template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-sam, aws-policies

After reading [S3WritePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-template-list.html#s3-write-policy) documentation, it's not clear if it allows multiple buckets.

I'm currently doing this:

```yaml
SampleLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Policies:
      - S3WritePolicy:
          BucketName: bucket-1
```

but if I wanted to include multiple buckets, i.e.:

```yaml
SampleLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Policies:
      - S3WritePolicy:
          BucketName: 
             - bucket-1
             - bucket-2
```

would this be **allowed**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does S3WritePolicy allow multiple buckets in AWS SAM template?

Yes.

> would this be allowed?

No, but the below would be allowed.

This is because it's a SAM policy template & is essentially generating a policy for a single bucket. You can however use it as many times as needed.

```yaml
SampleLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Policies:
      - S3WritePolicy:
          BucketName: 
             - bucket-1
      - S3WritePolicy:
          BucketName: 
             - bucket-2
```